# Autocomplete System.out.println("") like cw in C#

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

What is easiest way to tell Eclipse in Java code make `System.out.println("");` statement by writing some short phrase. I like `C#` way of pressing `cw 2 x tab` and get full code:

`cw 2 x tab` brings

```
Console.WriteLine("");
```

How to achieve the same in Eclipse Java project?

Comment: Type `sysout` followed by `ctrl+space`.

Comment: syso ctrl+space will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Templates

By default it is: print `sysout`  then   `Ctrl+Space`